# Scala: case class to avoid using ._

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala code like the following:

```
val new_rdd = rdd1.join(rdd2).map(x => (x._2._2, x._2._1))
```

I am not sure, but I think I could use `case class` to avoid the use of this `x._2._2`. Could you help me?

In this case, `rdd1` is `RDD[String,Array[String]]` and `rdd2` is `RDD[String,Array[Int]]`.

Comment: If you use case class you won't be able to join them because joining rdd required rdd to be pairedRDD and can you elaborate the meaning of `I think I could use case class to avoid the use of this x._2._2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a `case class` but I think this may be what you are looking for:

```
val new_rdd = rdd1.join(rdd2).map{ case (_, (a, b)) => (b, a) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could also be done:

```
case class Items(id: String,items: List[String])
case class ItemCounts(id: String,itemcounts: List[Int])

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
             Items("id1",List("item10","item2","item4")),
             Items("id2",List("item4","item9")),
             Items("id3",List("item1","item3"))))

val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
             ItemCounts("id1",List(100,200)),
             ItemCounts("id2",List(200,500,100,1100)),
             ItemCounts("id3",List(10))))
```

Create a pairRDD in order to join.

```
val ItemsRDD = rdd1.map(item => (item.id, item))
val ItemsCountsRDD= rdd2.map(itemcnts => (itemcnts.id, itemcnts))

ItemsRDD.join(ItemsCountsRDD).map(x => (x._2._1.id,x._2._2.itemcounts))
                             .collect.foreach(println)
```

Result looks like below:

```
(id3,List(10))
(id1,List(100, 200))
(id2,List(200, 500, 100, 1100))
```